# Prevent WPML from redirecting to default CPT name

Tags: redirect, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm working on a WP based site using the plugin WPML, and I've created a custom post type that has posts in two languages, English and Swedish. I need to be able to turn off the redirecting to the CPTs default name. For example, say I have a CPT called "references". In order to keep nice Urls I have links on the Swedish page that says "referenser" instead.
Now, for instance accessing **http://mysite.com/referenser/example-post/** takes me to **http://mysite.com/references/example-post/** .
While I retrieve the content anyway (WPML recognises the translation) this creates a little mess including the plugin on an ajax based site. Is there any way to turn off this redirect, or possibly set a translation name for the CPT?
Posted about this on the WPML support page but haven't got any response.

Answer (score 0):

Using the WPML Strings Translation module, you should have been able to translate the CPT slug-name so that the link will be translated instead of just copying of the English name.

Did you get help from the WPML forums? I'd like to followup if you did not.

Keith-R
WPML Community Manager

Comment: I got a reply from one of the team members stating that CPT slugs are as of the current version of WPML not translatable. This is supposed to be fixed in an upcoming version.